# After inflating and assigning a layout to view, the elements inside layout not seen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a custom view for 3D page turning which extends from View. Inside this custom view, I declare two views for foreground and background of page. I have declared different layouts for each foreground and background of page. Each layout has a Relativelayout and some elements inside that.

Inside custom view, I inflate the layouts and assign them to foreground and background view.

The RelativeLayout is seen but elements inside the layout is not showing up.

Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this. Am stuck ..

My customview code:

```
public class PageCurlView extends View {

    /** Our Log tag */
    private final static String TAG = "PageCurlView";


    private Context myAppContext;



    /** The context which owns us */
    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;


    /** LAGACY The current foreground */
    //private Bitmap mForeground;
    public View mForeground;

    /** LAGACY The current background */
    //private Bitmap mBackground;

    public View mBackground;

        /** LAGACY Current selected page */
    private int mIndex = 0;


    public Integer[] mViewIds = {
            R.layout.view_1,
            R.layout.view_2,
            R.layout.view_3,
            R.layout.view_4,
            R.layout.view_5,
            R.layout.view_6,
            R.layout.view_7,
            R.layout.view_8,
            R.layout.view_9,
            R.layout.view_10

       };

    private int mTotalViews = mViewIds.length;

    //Variables for inline sliders
    public ViewPager mInlinePager;
    public AwesomePagerAdapter mInlineAdapter;

    /**
     * Base
     * @param context
     */
    public PageCurlView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
        ResetClipEdge();
    }

    /**
     * Construct the object from an XML file. Valid Attributes:
     * 
     * @see android.view.View#View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
     */
    public PageCurlView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);

        // Get the data from the XML AttributeSet
        {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PageCurlView);

            // Get data
            bEnableDebugMode = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PageCurlView_enableDebugMode, bEnableDebugMode);
            mCurlSpeed = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlSpeed, mCurlSpeed);
            mUpdateRate = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_updateRate, mUpdateRate);
            mInitialEdgeOffset = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_initialEdgeOffset, mInitialEdgeOffset);
            mCurlMode = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlMode, mCurlMode);


            // recycle object (so it can be used by others)
            a.recycle();

        }

        ResetClipEdge();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the view
     */
    private final void init(Context context) {

        myAppContext = context;


        // Cache the context
        mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);

        // Base padding
        setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

        // The focus flags are needed
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        mMovement =  new Vector2D(0,0);
        mFinger = new Vector2D(0,0);
        mOldMovement = new Vector2D(0,0);


        // Set the default props, those come from an XML :D



        // Create some sample images

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  myAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view1 = inflater.inflate(mViewIds[0], null);   
        View view2 = inflater.inflate(mViewIds[1], null); 



        //Fix after coming back from vacation
        //For inline sliders

        mForeground = view1;
        mBackground = view2;

    }


    /**
     * Reset points to it's initial clip edge state
     */


    /**
     * Render the text
     * 
     * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
     */
    //@Override
    //protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //  super.onDraw(canvas);
    //  canvas.drawText(mText, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() - mAscent, mTextPaint);
    //}

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Curling. This handles touch events, the actual curling
    // implementations and so on.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------



    /**
     * Swap between the fore and back-ground.
     */
    @Deprecated
    private void SwapViews() {
        /*Bitmap temp = mForeground;
        mForeground = mBackground;
        mBackground = temp;*/

        View temp = mForeground;
        mForeground = mBackground;
        mBackground = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Swap to next view
     */
    private void nextView() { //Sushil need to uncomment
        int foreIndex = mIndex + 1;
        if(foreIndex >= /*mPages.size()*/mTotalViews) {
            //foreIndex = 0;
            foreIndex = mTotalViews-1;
        }
        int backIndex = foreIndex + 1;
        if(backIndex >= /*mPages.size()*/mTotalViews) {
            //backIndex = 0;
            backIndex = mTotalViews-1;
        }
        mIndex = foreIndex;

            setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Swap to previous view
     */
    private void previousView() { //Sushil need to uncomment
        Log.i("Sushil", "....previousView()....");
        int backIndex = mIndex;
        int foreIndex = backIndex - 1;
        if(foreIndex < 0) {
            foreIndex = /*mPages.size()*/0;
        }
        mIndex = foreIndex;
        setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);

    }

    /**
     * Set current fore and background
     * @param foreground - Foreground view index
     * @param background - Background view index
     */
    private void setViews(int foreground, int background) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  myAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view1 = inflater.inflate(mViewIds[foreground], null);   
        View view2 = inflater.inflate(mViewIds[background], null); 

        mForeground = view1;//(WebView)mPages.get(foreground);
        mBackground = view2;//(WebView)mPages.get(background);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Drawing methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Always refresh offsets
        mCurrentLeft = getLeft();
        mCurrentTop = getTop();

        // Translate the whole canvas
        //canvas.translate(mCurrentLeft, mCurrentTop);

        // We need to initialize all size data when we first draw the view
        if ( !bViewDrawn ) {
            bViewDrawn = true;
            onFirstDrawEvent(canvas);
        }

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        // Curl pages
        //DoPageCurl();

        // TODO: This just scales the views to the current
        // width and height. We should add some logic for:
        //  1) Maintain aspect ratio
        //  2) Uniform scale
        //  3) ...
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.left = 0;
        rect.top = 0;
        rect.bottom = getHeight();
        rect.right = getWidth();

        // First Page render
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        // Draw our elements
        drawForeground(canvas, rect, paint);
        drawBackground(canvas, rect, paint);

        drawCurlEdge(canvas);

        // Draw any debug info once we are done
        if ( bEnableDebugMode )
            drawDebug(canvas);

        // Check if we can re-enable input
        if ( bEnableInputAfterDraw )
        {
            bBlockTouchInput = false;
            bEnableInputAfterDraw = false;
        }

        // Restore canvas
        //canvas.restore();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Called on the first draw event of the view
     * @param canvas
     */
    protected void onFirstDrawEvent(Canvas canvas) {

        mFlipRadius = getWidth();

        ResetClipEdge();
        DoPageCurl();
    }

    /**
     * Draw the foreground
     * @param canvas
     * @param rect
     * @param paint
     */
    private void drawForeground( Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint ) {
        //canvas.drawBitmap(mForeground, null, rect, paint);
        //mForeground.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WebContent/Section01.html");

        mForeground.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
        mForeground.draw(canvas);


        // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D 
        // there is no page number 0 hehe)
        //drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Create a Path used as a mask to draw the background page
     * @return
     */
    private Path createBackgroundPath() {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(mA.x, mA.y);
        path.lineTo(mB.x, mB.y);
        path.lineTo(mC.x, mC.y);
        path.lineTo(mD.x, mD.y);
        path.lineTo(mA.x, mA.y);
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Draw the background image.
     * @param canvas
     * @param rect
     * @param paint
     */
    private void drawBackground( Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint ) {
        Path mask = createBackgroundPath();

        // Save current canvas so we do not mess it up
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipPath(mask);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, null, rect, paint);
        //mBackground.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WebContent/Section01.html");
        mBackground.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
        mBackground.draw(canvas);



        // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D 
        // there is no page number 0 hehe)
        drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);

        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

One of my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/sampletextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:text="VIEW 1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

"You're doing it wrong"

Your custom View contains bunch of another views, so logically it should be `ViewGroup` (or subclass of it) with proper implementation, not just `View`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes. I realized that that it should be RelativeLayout in my case or ViewGroup. But am not able to write onLayout function properly. can you please guide me with some code example in my case.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher just check the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: I had seen this doc but actually I was expecting step by step tutorial. Anyhow thanks for helping :)

Answer (score -1):

set layout params after inflating views.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams([width], [heigth]);
//assign additional params like below, above, to right or to left or others relative layout params
inflatedView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: It didnt work. Actually if I just keep a textview in xml and remove RelativeLaout, it shows up fine. But I need RelativeLayout as I have to put more elements inside it..Thanks for help anyway