# Can't add views to ViewGroups added programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

I can't add child views to a ViewGroup that I added programmatically.

First I create a GroupView (`_view`) and add it to the Background RelativeLayout (`_root`) like this...

```
            _view = new ViewGroup(MainActivity.this) {
                @Override
                protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                }
            };

            _view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
            _view.setLayoutParams(params);
            _view.setTranslationX(0);
            _view.setTranslationY(positionY - 80);
            selectView(_view);

            _root.addView(_view);

            _view.setTag(R.string.viewID, "" + viewNum);
            _view.setTag(R.string.viewSelected, "" + 0);
            viewNum ++;
```

That works fine. Then I try to add a view to that new GroupView (`_view`) like this...

```
            ImageView dragIcon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            dragIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.drabicon);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            imgParams.setMargins(0,0,30,0);
            dragIcon.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
            dragIcon.setTranslationY(_view.getTranslationY());

            _view.addView(dragIcon); // This Is What I Want, But This Doesn't Work.

            //_root.addView(dragIcon); // Don't Want This, But This Works.
```

But it doesn't get added, or it isn't visible or something. Now if i use the Background RelativeLayout (`_root`) like this `_root.addView(dragIcon);` It works fine, the ImageView gets added.

So why doesn't work with the `_view` ViewGroup, `_view.addView(dragIcon)`?

Comment: avoid using _VarName for instance variable, even android studio code inspect will suggest you to Use m prefix for non-public and non-static fields.

Comment: Make sure that you are adding dragIcon to _view an and after that _view to _root.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `ViewGroup`, which is an abstract class you should implement the abstract method `onLayout` in which each `layout` method of each child of the viewgroup must be called. For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17516300/3929188) answer.

I think you can use FrameLayout which is a subclass ViewGroup. It has the `onLayout` method implemented so you dont have the burden to implementing it again.

Here is working code for ViewGroup where I plainly called the `layout` method of the only one child (dragIcon).

**ExampleActivity.java**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewGroup _view ;
    RelativeLayout _root;
    ImageView dragIcon;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        _root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.exampleLayout);

        _view  = new ViewGroup(ExampleActivity.this) {
            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
                dragIcon.layout(l, t, r, b); //CHECK THIS
            }
        };

        _view .setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        _view .setLayoutParams(params);
        _view .setTranslationX(0);
        _view .setTranslationY(80);
       // selectView(_view);

        _root.addView(_view );

        _view .setTag(R.string.app_name, "" );
        _view .setTag(R.string.app_name, "" + 0);


        dragIcon = new ImageView(ExampleActivity.this);
        dragIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imgParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        _view .addView(dragIcon); // This Is What I Want, But This Doesn't Work.

        //sample_root.addView(dragIcon); // Don't Want This, But This Works.
    }

}
```

**activity_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/exampleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.anil.raceorganizer.ExampleActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```